# Mail.app messages won't stay filed/deleted

Tags: mail.app

I use Mail.app connected to my work's IMAP server.  About two weeks ago I noticed that when I moved messages from the INBOX to an Archive folder, or delete the messages, some eventually come back to the INBOX.  I haven't been able to catch the moment at which they come back, but they definitely do.

This makes it really hard to get things done as my INBOX is just getting fuller and fuller of mail I've already processed and dealt with.  I'm not sure how to diagnose or fix the problem.

Comment: Did you change your Password two weeks ago? Mail would need to be able to communicate back to your mail server to give it instructions, otherwise it may do a form of check on your inbox, see that the message is missing and push the message to your phone again, to make the two in sync. While I would think that changing your password would stop you from being able to send and receive any mail on your device if you forgot to change the PW, maybe the set up of your mail server allows for emails to transfer, but will not execute anything else. As you said it is work email, is there an admin?

Comment: @AMR: Thanks for picking up on this.  No, I hadn't changed the password.